# Something like stringByAppendingString for a double

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, math

Im trying to make a calculator app. I want it to conform with thing like order of operations, etc. The way I thought do this is to have the numbers and the operation added to the end of a double when an operation is pressed. I can't find any way to add numbers and an operation (+,-,*,/) to the end of a double, or any number related class in objective c.

If you know of any way to do this, or have a different idea on how to do this that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to convert your double into a string ? and then use concatenation ?

Comment: @KIDdAe I tried doing this in a string and converting it to double but it wouldn't add the actual problem to the double. The operations wouldn't go over to the double. So if the string was `25 + 12` the double would only be 25

Comment: uh ? And what are you expecting ? A double with the value 32 ?
Please add example, your question is really not clear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good approach on many levels. First, just adding an operation to the "end" of a number (whatever you mean by "end" here) does not get you to order-of-operation. You need to keep track of the entire expression (or at least more than just the last operand). Since you're working in ObjC, you'll probably want an object-oriented approach to manage your expressions. Google for "object oriented calculator." There are many examples. (Do not worry whether the example is in ObjC; you should be able to apply the same object model in any OOP language.) @trojanfoe offers the beginnings of this, but getting to correct order-of-operation is more complicated. Luckily, it's been solved many times. See [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) for one ObjC solution.

The next thing that's going to bite you is that `double` is a dangerous type for a calculator. Your user expects to work in Base-10. `double` works in Base-2. There are going to be rounding errors, and you wind up with results like 4.999999999 when you clearly meant 5. If you intend to display decimal, then work in decimal. Cocoa offers the `NSDecimalNumber` class for this, as well as the `NSDecimal` Foundation type.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the answer

Comment: seems the question was clear to you. +1

Answer (score 0):

As the user types in their operations, you need to collect them, so you need a custom object for each operation:

```
typedef enum {
    CalcOperatonTypeValue,    // value is valid
    CalcOperatonTypeAdd,      // +
    CalcOperatonTypeSub,      // -
    CalcOperatonTypeMult,     // *
    CalcOperatonTypeDiv       // %
} CalcOperationType;

@interface CalcOperation : NSObject
@property (assign) CalcOperationType type;
@property (assign) double value;
@end
```

Then collect these into a mutable array as the user performs their operation (note that `CalcOperation.value` is only valid when `type` is `CalcOperatonTypeValue`).

And then when you want to know what the current value is (to display), perform something like this:

```
double total = 0.0, lastValue = 0.0;
for (CalcOperation *op in operations) {
    switch (op.type) {
    case CalcOperatonTypeValue:
        lastValue = op.value;
        break;
    case CalcOperatonTypeAdd:
        total += lastValue;
        break;
    case CalcOperatonTypeSub:
        total -= lastValue;
        break;
    case CalcOperatonTypeMult:
        total *= lastValue;
        break;
    case CalcOperatonTypeDiv:
        total /= lastValue;
        break;
    default:
        NSAssert(NO, @"Invalid operation type");
        break;
    }
}
```

Note: there is a lot more error checking that needs to be done before this becomes solid.